# Not a Tramp file name

Tags: tramp

windows 10 (64 bit), emacs 26.1

I try to connect by Tramp mode from Windows to remote Linux machine.

I use this command:

```
C-x C-f
```

and then ip of remote machine (ip address):

```
 /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:
```

but I get error:

```
Error running timer: (user-error "Not a Tramp file name: \"/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:\"")
```

Comment: Try `/ssh:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/path/to/file`.

Comment: I try this: "/ssh:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:"     but get error: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

Comment: Have you tried entering ip of said machine rather than `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I always enter ip address

Comment: Do you have `ssh` installed and avaiable in your `PATH`?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 If I in shell run "ssh" then I get: "ssh'
ssh
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface] ...

Comment: Have you tried doing this from emacs with no init file (`emacs -q`)?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I get this error: Tramp: Opening connection for myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx using ssh...
Tramp: Sending command ‘ssh -l myuser -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx && exit || exit’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...
Tramp failed to connect.  If this happens repeatedly, try
    ‘M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection’

Comment: I don't believe this can be answered on sx. Please make a Tramp bug report, and include the debug buffer produced with `tramp-verbose` set to 10. The Tramp manual tells you the details.

Answer (score 2):

See Emacs NEWS (`C-h n`):

> *** The method part of remote file names is mandatory now. A valid remote file name starts with "/method:host:" or "/method:user@host:".
>
> *** The new pseudo method "-" is a marker for the default method. "/-::" is the shortest remote file name then.
>
> *** The command 'tramp-change-syntax' allows you to choose an alternative remote file name syntax.